# Javascript: Is there a way to send a cash drawer kick code?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to make a cash drawer kick open. The command that needs to be sent to the drawer, by way of the receipt printer, is "chr(27).chr(112).chr(0).chr(100).chr(250)". Is there a way to send this command through javascript or other web based language. I want the cash drawer to only open only during certain receipt prints.

Comment: Well, how can you talk to the printer? Does it understand HTTP? Is it connected to something that can run Javascript?

Answer (score 5):

For background first see my answer here [How to print a receipt through Receipt Printer from Web Page(.aspx)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13082482/495455)

The ESC/P cash draw code you have is correct as per: http://www.beaglehardware.com/howtoprogramcashdrawer.html

The problem is discussed here: https://code.google.com/p/jzebra/issues/detail?id=134

> [POS world](http://www.posworld.com/epescposcasd.html) says the kickout code is: 1B 70 00 40 F0, however the "00"
>   won't work (it's a limitation of the web browser)

Download [jZebra](https://code.google.com/archive/p/jzebra/downloads) - it's now evolved into the [qz-print](https://github.com/qzind/qz-print) library, put the jar file in the project directory and the first method in this [jzebra mail thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/jzebra-users/jkZ3x_eBbCY/oTolrGG1jfoJ) works for me:

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>
    <input type=button onClick="openCashDrawer()" value="Open Cash Drawer">
    <applet name="jzebra" code="jzebra.PrintApplet.class" archive="./jar/jzebra.jar" width="100" height="100">
        <param name="printer" value="zebra">
</applet>

<script>
function chr(i) {
    return String.fromCharCode(i);
} 

function openCashDrawer() {
    document.jzebra.append(chr(27) + "\x70" + "\x30" + chr(25) + chr(25) + "\r");
    document.jzebra.print();
}
</script>
```

The base64 and appendFile methods discussed in that thread didn't work for me but apparently `appendFile(file with raw ESC/P Commands)` and `append64(base64)` do workaround the "Chr(0)" limitation.

Comment: +1 for ans, I have very less knowledge about applet, my application is php javascript, do you know  for this  to work, where do i have to download the plugin.

Comment: @BhavinRana I've updated this and my other answer with the new jZebra library, looks like its called **qz-print** these days. It will work as long as the end users follow the instructions to set up the receipt printer (naming it jZebra) and connect the RJ45 cord to the Cash Drawer and send the correct cash drawer opening code.