# How to print a receipt through Receipt Printer from Web Page(.aspx)?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, firefox, printing, thermal-printer

Added IFrame on web page & given source as text file.It is working fine on Common printer.But,unable to print receipt through Receipt printer.It is coming as blank paper.

Printer name : **PR-85 Thermal printer** .Click below link to see printer specification details..

http://www.essae.com/popup_html/pr-85.html

Anybody have solution ?

[image]

Comment: What are you trying to print?

Comment: It is just a common Point Of Sales Receipt which supports A8 size.

Comment: Please go through post again..Added image.

Comment: Working in IE.But,not in Firefox & Chrome.Any clues ?

Comment: Used [jZebra](http://code.google.com/p/jzebra/) applet.Working fine....We can send raw text with Partial cut command..

Comment: @SridharReddyBommireddy I was searching for this applet for ages, I added the instructions to get it working as an answer as I didn't notice your comment when I was researching earlier.