# How command USB Epson TM-T88V esc printers?

Tags: usb, thermal-printer, epson, epos

How can I send raw ESC commands and read printer status replies to a USB printer like Epson TM-T88V?
Maybe I'm looking for dll or windows sdk. Please consider that I'm looking for an SDK for NON-intelligent printers so ePos SDK is not suitable.

Now I can printer and read printer status using an Epson tool that converts an USB printer port to a virtual serial port. Is this the only way to communicate with these USB printers?

Comment: Have you found an answer to your question?

Comment: No, I'm still using the virtual com port tool.

Comment: I too am searching for a solution. Basically, I need to send commands to my epson tm-t82 (USB) printer via my web app (javascript). Found these two solutions:- https://medium.com/@davidkelley87/javascript-interface-for-esc-pos-18123ead9219 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13082482/how-to-print-a-receipt-through-receipt-printer-from-web-page-aspx. Will try these tomorrow. I hope the above solutions will help you.

Comment: I think the ePos printer should be suitable for js app, but I will look at your link. Thanks