# Printers with nonexistent OPOS drivers

Tags: c#, printing, thermal-printer, opos

I am developing a POS using OPOS for printing (in c#), so far I have only found that Epson has a tool for installing OPOS for any of its models, but I haven't found any driver or tool to install OPOS for any other printer brand (For example: Ec Line 80320). My question is: What can I do to make a printer work with OPOS if the drivers do not exist?

Comment: Maybe try this method https://stackoverflow.com/q/13082482/495455

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OPOS Control is tightly coupled with hardware, and OPOS Control across vendors will not exist.

If you need to use hardware that does not have OPOS Control, give up OPOS and use it in the way provided by that vendor.
If you are ECLine 80320 in your example, you will use the Windows standard printing API.

If your application is already completed as using OPOS, please change to hardware supporting OPOS.

You can save system construction time by either of the above methods.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [PrintRawHelper](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29564132/2733492) and to generate the the ESC/POS command use this [nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/PrinterUtility) package [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0mC_yvT3abw) you have a good tutorial  how to use that library.

Comment: i think the guy in the tutorial is using the OPOS drivers of the printer, isnt it?

Comment: the printing functionally he is showing is not working that's why I told you to use PrintRawHelper  `RawPrinterHelper.SendStringToPrinter(printerName, Encoding.Default.GetString(bytes))`